# NHibernate Equals and GetHashCode

Tags: nhibernate

Why do I need to override Equals and GetHash code in my Entities when using NHibernate? Today I got this error

```
System.ApplicationException : For property 'Person' expected 'Domain.Person'
of type 'Domain.Person' but got 'PersonProxy20252a6926f841a8b45e327292fe0eae'
of type 'Domain.Person'
```

Now I have read(but not confirmed) that This is because I havent overridden `Equals` and `GetHashCode` in my Entity. My question is do I need to do this AND do I need override both `Equals(Object obj)` and `Equals(Person person)` I am assuming I need to inherit from `IEquatable<Person>` and do so.

Comment: Can you post the full exception? (with stack trace and inner exceptions)

Answer (score 1):

Ok totally CANT override Equals(Person person) for IEquatable in fact if you do it breaks